# Wait Cursor issue - Need help

Tags: .net

I have been searching in the net as well here to get some help/info on wait cursors, but couldn't find direct answer.

I am having web project built in vs 2008 c#. As usual I have master page and child pages as well some user controls placed on some of the child pages. As child pages or user controls will not have  or  I am little confusion on how to use wait cursor on the following scenarios

1) Page load. Wait cursor automatically coming in google chrome, but not in IE when page is loading. There is some database functionality attached in each child page directly or through user controls.

2) Button click on either child page or in user control

Once the processing is over, the cursor should come back to normal.

Any help with some sample would be greatly appreciated, as I am working on this since 4 days without any proper solutions so far.

I have created sample web project to replicate the problem, I can send for reproducing.

Answer (score 0):

Use css to set cursor of body as "Wait" when button is clicked. And when page is processed, set them to "Default". [Wait cursor over entire html page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192900/wait-cursor-over-entire-html-page)

Comment: This is not html page. It is aspx web project and using Ajax in some pages.

Comment: No wait cursor showing in one case and cannot put wait cursor in another case

Answer (score 0):

Have you already checked with some tool (like fiddler) whether loading of the page is really done? If youre not using CSS for changing the cursor, the problem might be that some request is still running: this would then be the point for further investigation.