# Change Mouse Cursor for whole page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a drag UI program, where the mouse cursor on the draggable element changes to a grabbing hand on click.

The problem is, I allow the drag to happen anywhere on screen, and the cursor changes over anchor tags, etc...

I've tried `$('*').addClass('grabbing')`, but it's REALLY expensive.

Is there a simple easy code efficient way to handle this?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192900/wait-cursor-over-entire-html-page

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Do it at the CSS level:

```
* {
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

doing it in jquery forces it to iterate every single node in the dom and rewrite its css classes. On a long document, that's a huge waste of time.

Comment: But this will always be active. The cursor needs to change only while the mouse is down. It needs to happen in Javascript somehow.

Comment: You can dynamically add/remove css rules via javascript. Just do it from within the onmousedown/onmouseup and it should be quicker than adding/removing classes from every dom node on the page.

Comment: @Mark B Cool. Can you provide a new answer with an example? I'll give it a shot and if it works right I'll mark it.

Comment: Same problem as the other answer - Other CSS elements and classes will override this if they specify a cursor.

Comment: @mike: there's always `!important`.

Comment: @MarcB It seems I can add but not remove with this. If you figure out the code and post it as an answer I'll mark it. There is a JQuery Rule plugin that might work.

Comment: @Wesley: .cssRules and .rules are just arrays. you can use regular array operations to remove a particular rule by deleting its corresponding array element.

Comment: Can add as a subclass with !important to preserve without dynamically adding rules.

`body.loading-cursor *{
    cursor: wait !important;
}`

Comment: still doesn't set the cursor for the whole page when BODY is shorter than 100%

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$('body').addClass('grabbing');
```

OR

```
$(document).addClass('grabbing');
```

//EDITED ANSWER

```
$('body').mousedown(function(e){
    $(this).css({'cursor':'pointer'});
}).mouseup(function(e){
    $(this).css({'cursor':'auto'});
});
```

If you firebug is on, you can see the changes in body style tag. But some how it's not working. You can take it as a reference and try similar approach the get solution.

Comment: Won't hire zindex elements override that?

Comment: @MikeChristensen Correct. This won't quite do it.

Answer (score 2):

I tried most of these, but not all elements will display the cursor. The quick and dirty method is to iterate the entire dom and set the cursor for each element.

```
document.querySelectorAll('*').forEach(function(node) {
    node.style.cursor = 'progress';
});
```

Execute ajax or whatever here....Followed by:

```
document.querySelectorAll('*').forEach(function(node) {
    node.style.cursor = 'default';
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Though this is not a direct answer to this question but I want to draw attentions to that we can solve the problem differently.

By putting an empty fullscreen div on top of everything except drop zones, activate it after `mousedown` event. So we can simply change cursor for entire screen through `:hover` class of that div .

Answer (score 1):

When you need it, you can invoke a single line of javascript:

```
document.body.style.setProperty('cursor', 'pointer');
```

When you want to undo it again, you can execute another single line:

```
document.body.removeAttribute('style');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new stylesheet to the page/site.

https://codepen.io/Swell_boy/pen/oNMBbKq

```
const css = "* { cursor: grabbing !important; }",
  styletag = document.createElement("style");

styletag.type = "text/css";
if (styletag.styleSheet) {
  styletag.styleSheet.cssText = css;
} else {
  styletag.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
}

document.addEventListener("mouseup", function myFunction_Default() {
  styletag.remove();
});

document.addEventListener("mousedown", function myFunction_Grab() {
  document.body.appendChild(styletag);
});
```