# displaying process(or wait) cursor with jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cursor

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //other stuff
    $(".active_item").click(function() {
        $("body").css("cursor", "progress"); //tried wait instead of progress as well
        window.setTimeout(someLength,4000);//just to make sure we do switch back at some point
        $('#list tbody tr').each(function(i) {
            $(this).removeClass('invisible_row');
        });
        $("#list tbody tr").show();
        $('.catnav').each(function(i) {
            $(this).removeClass('current_category');
        });
        $("body").css("cursor", "default");
    });
});
```

I've checked other questions like [Changing cursor to waiting in javascript/jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9681080/changing-cursor-to-waiting-in-javascript-jquery)

but in my code it doesn't work (the cursor does not change to "`progress`", or "`wait`" if I choose that one).

Comment: You're setting the cursor and then immediately setting it back. There's no net effect.

Comment: to put it another way, `$("body").css("cursor", "progress").css("cursor", "default")` would be identical to what you're currently doing with the cursor.

Comment: Oh I see, you mean because of the async functions?

Comment: the only async-ish function you have is the setTimeout, is that what you're referring to?

Comment: hmm. OK. So I set the cursor to progress. Then I call each, show, and each. I would like to set the cursor back when these three functions are done...But I am setting the cursor back before those three have finished. Is this the issue?

Comment: Obviously there's something very fundamental I haven't understood in javascript...

Answer (score 0):

You could try and use the show() function as a timer, so that your cursor will stay in 'progress' at least a second.

> $("#list tbody tr").show(1000 // Enter the time you want here , 
>   function(){$("body").css("cursor", "default");});

That way your cursor will reverse back to default after the function show() completes, which takes 1 second (in my example).

You can check [.show() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/show/) for more information.

Comment: I had tried this as well, but still there's no progress cursor. This even breaks my code for some reason...thanks anyway