# Changing the mouse icon to 'waiting' no matter where it is

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, icons, mouse

I am developing a web form that pulls and updates customer information and it has multiple ajax requests that are somewhat slow due (2-4 seconds). I added a 'waiting' cursor whenever the page is waiting for results. However, a lot of the time the page is waiting for the request, users either leave their cursor on a button or a table (via tabulator) so the cursor stays as the hand/click cursor and the loading wheel is not visible. If the user moves the mouse off the button/table it changes to the loading wheel. I am already using jQuery to do the ajax calls so I am using this piece of code:

`$(document.body).css({'cursor' : 'wait'});`

Is there a way that I can force the icon to the loading wheel, no matter what state it is in?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing cursor to waiting in javascript/jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9681080/changing-cursor-to-waiting-in-javascript-jquery)

Comment: Could you also use the "pointer-events" property (pointer-events: none;) to disable any default events, while the request is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `!important` to override the css set on buttons, links, input and body.

```
$("body,a,button,input").css("cssText", "cursor:wait !important;");
```

Note the usage of cssText above.

You could also specify `*` as your selector, but that would be pretty reckless.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding `cursor: wait;` to multiple elements on your page, I suggest you add a class to your body.

```
$(document.body).addClass('loading');
```

---

In your CSS, you can define your loading-cursor to show everywhere.

```
.loading * {
  cursor: wait !important;
}
```